# Immutable Scala Collection

Tags: scala, collections, functional-programming, immutability, immutable-collections

I have this Scala code that spits out unique random numbers for the Italian lottery:

```
object Enalotto {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val numbers = scala.collection.mutable.SortedSet[Int]()
    val r = scala.util.Random

    while(numbers.size < 6) {
        numbers += r.nextInt(90) + 1
    }

    for ((number, index) <- numbers.view.zipWithIndex) {
        if(number < 10) print("0")
        print(number)
        if(index < 5) print(" - ")
    }

    println("")
  }
}
```

I would like to ask, how would you write the same program with an immutable collection, in a more appropriate functional-style programming?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to use immutable collection here? It's possible (e.g. recursion since you don't know original collection size), but won't be justified, at least not in `while` loop.

Comment: One possible solution (works with mutable sets too if you replace `+` with `+=`): `Stream.iterate(collection.immutable.SortedSet[Int]())(_ + (util.Random.nextInt(90) + 1)).dropWhile(_.size < 6).head`

Comment: It was just for the sake of the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need 6 unique numbers, it's easiest to randomly shuffle the entire range and just take the first six from the result:

```
val numbers = util.Random.shuffle(1 to 90).take(6).sorted
val formatted = numbers map {"%02d".format(_)} mkString " - "
println(formatted)
```

Comment: What happens if you need distinct 6 from `1 to 1000000`?

Answer (score 3):

```
List.iterate(0,7)(_ => util.Random.nextInt(90) + 1)
  .tail
  .sorted
  .mkString(" - ")
```

This is your generator and your formatter.

---

Explanation: I'm calling the `iterate()` method of the `List` companion object. It creates a new `List` of 7 elements, starting with the value 0. For every value after that it invokes the anonymous function that generates a random value.

Now we have our list. Take the `tail` because we're actually not interested in the starting 0 value.

Sort the result, and turn the `List` into a `String` with the elements separated by the string " - ".

Comment: So iterate is partial function as I understand? and it accepting tail as list to process.??

Comment: @PavelOliynyk, explanation added.

Comment: "Use map to zero numbers less than 10," Er, that's not what the OP's original does. That zero-padded single digit numbers!

Comment: Look well at my code: the while loop could iterate not just 6 times, but iterates till the collection has 6 elements, in fact an equal random number would not be added in a set. Your answer is really good, but I'm afraid it iterates only 6 times, am I wrong?

Comment: @MirkoBenedetti So you accepted "really good", but completely wrong answer? You want 6 distinct numbers, right?

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace mutable collection with immutable
2. Add function to add random number like:

Option 1.

```
def addNumber(l: List[Int], n : Int) : List[Int] = n::l
```

Option 2. use generators:

```
for{
  i <- 0 to 6
  r = scala.util.Random
} yield  r;
```

Generally speaking there are number of way you can code in FP way. 
Rest of the code looks ok.

Comment: Your result type is `Vector`, not `SortedSet`.

Comment: val list = {
  for{
    i <- 0 to 6
    r = scala.util.Random
  } yield  r
 }.toList

Comment: It depends what you planning to do next ... are you ok to with evaluation models ??

Comment: Depends on how fast you want it to be, conversion from `Vector` to `List` (or `SortedSet`) takes time.

Comment: Vectors faster in terms of performance:)) all depends what is your plan

Comment: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html